How to best cover this dryer vent?
The dryer exhaust hose seemingly goes from a 4in to 3in inside the home. Not sure what the previous owner did but it is exposed (SHOCKED no critters are inside) and the opening is a bit awkward with the board below occluding the full diameter of the hose. No 3in or 4in flush fixtures will fit. I took a 3 to 4in piece and attached it to a louvered opening per the pic below. This “fits” in the opening of the dryer vent.
Do you propose a different solution or how would you recommend I seal the gaps? Window and door spray foam? This is seemingly not waterproof. Caulk the gaps first? A unique solution with a piece of siding above to deflect water?
Thank you!

No pictures yet.
